# Is it possible to reduce generic objects with unknown property names in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, functional-programming

Is it possible to two reduce objects into one by summing their properties like so for any generic object

```
const A = {x:1, y:1, z:1}
const B = {x:2, y:2, z:2}
// result {x:3, y:3, z:3}
```

I am hoping to get some function

```
function reduceObjects<T extends {[readonly key: string]: number}>(previousObject:T, currentObject:T) => T
```

when I try this solution

```
function reduceObjectsGeneric<T extends {readonly [key: string]: number}>(currentValue: T , previousValue: T): T {
  const result = Object.assign({}, previousValue);


  Object.keys(previousValue).forEach((k) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line functional/immutable-data
    result[k]=previousValue[k]+currentValue[k]
  })

  return result
}
```

I get the following error in the inner loop

> Type 'string' cannot be used to index type '{} & T'.ts(2536)

What is the functional way to implement this behaviour?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for adding your attempt. I see you have a line there to suppress an eslint error. Are you also happy to use type assertions, or trying hard to *avoid* type assertions? (I think of the latter as best practice, though for an isolated function like this I'd probably be happy enough to use them.)

Comment: I am trying to avoid type assertions as I’d like to keep this function generic for any object with essentially all of its properties as numbers ( or anything that implements the + operator )

Comment: Binary `+` (the `+` that takes two operands) is "defined" for any type in JavaScript, but coerces its operands to either numbers or strings; the result is always a number or string. That's baked into the language (and not going to change). [This](https://tsplay.dev/mplagm) is the closest I could get in the time I could spend on it, and still needs two more type assertions (making three in total) to make it work. (the first type assertion is reasonable to me.) So I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834191/) about why the second and third assertions would be needed.

Comment: Can we please have this question reopened? I am not sure who closed this as I have clearly narrowed the question down as much as a I can and I have provided a reasonable amount of thought. This is quite unfair and discouraging for people who are new to the platform.

Comment: You forgot to specify the `extends {[key: string]: number}` in your attempt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional approach would be (but probably not clean)

```js
function reduceObjects<T extends { [key: string]: number }>(a: T, b: T): T {
  return Object.keys(a).reduce(
    (acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: a[key] + b[key] }),
    b
  );
}
```

First, you get the keys of object "a" using `Object.keys`.
Then you use the `Array.reduce` method of JavaScript to iterate over the keys and assign it to the "key" of the "acc" object.

Answer (score 1):

A generic `reduceWith` could provide the necessary scaffolding:

```
type ReduceObjectsWith = <
  V extends unknown, T = Record<PropertyKey, V>
>(fn: (acc: T, pair: [PropertyKey, V]) => T) => (...objs: T[]) => T;

type ReduceWithSum = ReduceObjectsWith<number>
```

```js
const reduceObjectsWith = (fn) => (...objs) => objs.reduce(
  (res, curr) => Object.entries(curr).reduce(fn, res), 
  {},
);

const reduceWithSum = reduceObjectsWith(
  (res, [key, value]) => ({ 
    ...res, 
    [key]: value + (res[key] ?? 0),
  }),
);

console.log(
  reduceWithSum(
    {x: 1, y: 1, z: 1},
    {x: 2, y: 2, z: 2},
    {x: -2, y: 2, z: 5},
    {x: -1, y: 0, z: 32},
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach that uses a read-only functional approach that passes most es-lint rules:

```
function reducer<T extends {readonly [key: string]: unknown|number}>(object1: Partial<T>, object2: Partial<T>): T {
  return Array.from(new Set([...Object.keys(object1),...Object.keys(object2)]).values()).reduce(
    (p: T, c: string) => {
      if ((object1[c] instanceof Object)) {
        return { [c]: reducer(object1[c] as Partial<T>, (object2[c] ?? {}) as Partial<T>),...p}
      }
      const v1 = object1[c]??ZERO
      const v2 = object2[c]??ZERO
      return {[c]: (v1 as number)+(v2 as number),...p,}
    }, {} as T
  )
}
```