# Why can I index by string to get a property value but not to set it?

Tags: typescript

I was trying to solve [this other question's problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809891/is-it-possible-to-reduce-generic-objects-with-unknown-property-names-in-typescri) which involves iterating through two objects of the same unknown type and adding together their number-typed properties without type assertions (if possible).

I got close (I thought I had it down to one type assertion) but I'm flummoxed by something I ran into: Why in the following can I use `key` to index `result` and `currentValue` when *getting* the value of a property, but not when *setting* the value of a property?

```typescript
const a = {x:1, y:1, z:1};
const b = {x:2, y:2, z:2};

function reduceObjects<T extends {[key: string]: any}>(currentValue: T, previousValue: T): T {
    const result = Object.assign({}, previousValue) as T;

    for (const key of Object.keys(result)) {
        const prev = result[key];
        //           ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− why is this okay...
        const curr = currentValue[key];
        if (typeof prev === "number" && typeof curr === "number") {
            result[key] = prev + curr;
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^^−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−− ...but this isn't?
        //                 "Type 'string' cannot be used to index type 'T'.(2536)"
        } else if (typeof prev === "string" && typeof curr === "string") {
            result[key] = prev + curr;
        //  ^^^^^^^^^^^ (same error here of course)
        }
    }

    return result;
}

const c = reduceObjects(a, b);
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gDwFwEYA0MCe2eAXtgL4DcAUKJLAEZKqYBMehbMpLlVVAZgFcwwKAEtwMAE4BTACaDgMgPL0AVjNEQAPABUYMtFBlg5EVAG0A1jMIxoUsWADmAXQzww+MgD4AFMCCUrJgUABqcAA2gjIeungADrIAbhKCEBHRsTC6AJRxqFQwxTC00NIyEIKRsMiqGqIAdHAQEGLOYH4oZIkpaRlRMbnw5rrURSX8IFIwAeDlNvgwIPww9ZpQjYsQfrJVNbnDKBMlJWWwSTLJTHvVUNa2rtSnpwD0ry+fAHo-v39fgCQiIHAkGgsHg4EwADuAAslmJzFAYQjllY4PhGpiTi9zqUgjNkIFgiZwoMZA98E9sacxKs-FB8AkZCsYJdrogOTAAERgQQAW3oMikXJgADJRTAGUyWUSCZyefzBcKjtTPhV9vdFq4mGyYABqPHBZ5q97Ff7miGWq3WoEwTGNeiCWBIlEIsAAcigAH5VcVTWqA9zdIyZDB3Q4nM53aU4GAwCAGKH0vJJSAYE45IZJSGw7p3Y0-CwAKwAZgAbLkub6YGQDJEIKHabMpczVrqOcguRGXCLxdnpatZUh5d3nFyVYGSrcahTtchdQbZcbPv7zf9ZhA4HzQ0KpNMYDChaGZSAgg3ctWyNir9jZFAgmB1XdqDfccAbvJFCp1BsdnA8PQuQUEAA)

My question is **why** is the error there. I'm not really trying to fix it (though if you can fix the above — probably with a different approach entirely — I do recommend you post an answer to the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809891/is-it-possible-to-reduce-generic-objects-with-unknown-property-names-in-typescri) ). I want to understand **why** it matters whether I'm getting or setting the property.

[Titian Cernicova Dragomir](https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir) pointed out that this changed between [v3.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.3.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gDwFwEYA0MCe2eAXtgL4DcAUKJLAEZKqYBMehbMpLlVVAZgFcwwKAEtwMAE4BTACaDgMgPL0AVjNEQAPABUYMtFBlg5EVAG0A1jMIxoUsWADmAXQzww+MgD4AFMCCUrJgUABqcAA2gjIeungADrIAbhKCEBHRsTC6AJRxqFQwxTC00NIyEIKRsMiqGqIAdHAQEGLOYH4oZIkpaRlRMbnw5rrURSX8IFIwAeDlNvgwIPww9ZpQjYsQfrJVNbnDKBMlJWWwSTLJTHvVUNa2rtSnpwD0ry+fAHo-v39fgCQiIHAkGgsHg4EwADuAAslmJzFAYQjllY4PhGpiTi9zqUgjNkIFgiZwoMZA98E9sacxKs-FB8AkZCsYJdrogOTAAERgQQAW3oMikXJgADJRTAGUyWUSCZyefzBcKjtTPhV9vdFq4mGyYABqPHBZ5q97Ff7miGWq3WoEwTGNeiCWBIlEIsAAcigAH5VcVTWqA9zdIyZDB3Q4nM53aU4GAwCAGKH0vJJSAYE45IZJSGw7p3Y0-CwAKwAZgAbLkub6YGQDJEIKHabMpczVrqOcguRGXCLxdnpatZUh5d3nFyVYGSrcahTtchdQbZcbPv7zf9ZhA4HzQ0KpNMYDChaGZSAgg3ctWyNir9jZFAgmB1XdqDfccAbvJFCp1BsdnA8PQuQUEAA) (where it worked) and [v3.5 onward](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=3.5.1#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gDwFwEYA0MCe2eAXtgL4DcAUKJLAEZKqYBMehbMpLlVVAZgFcwwKAEtwMAE4BTACaDgMgPL0AVjNEQAPABUYMtFBlg5EVAG0A1jMIxoUsWADmAXQzww+MgD4AFMCCUrJgUABqcAA2gjIeungADrIAbhKCEBHRsTC6AJRxqFQwxTC00NIyEIKRsMiqGqIAdHAQEGLOYH4oZIkpaRlRMbnw5rrURSX8IFIwAeDlNvgwIPww9ZpQjYsQfrJVNbnDKBMlJWWwSTLJTHvVUNa2rtSnpwD0ry+fAHo-v39fgCQiIHAkGgsHg4EwADuAAslmJzFAYQjllY4PhGpiTi9zqUgjNkIFgiZwoMZA98E9sacxKs-FB8AkZCsYJdrogOTAAERgQQAW3oMikXJgADJRTAGUyWUSCZyefzBcKjtTPhV9vdFq4mGyYABqPHBZ5q97Ff7miGWq3WoEwTGNeiCWBIlEIsAAcigAH5VcVTWqA9zdIyZDB3Q4nM53aU4GAwCAGKH0vJJSAYE45IZJSGw7p3Y0-CwAKwAZgAbLkub6YGQDJEIKHabMpczVrqOcguRGXCLxdnpatZUh5d3nFyVYGSrcahTtchdQbZcbPv7zf9ZhA4HzQ0KpNMYDChaGZSAgg3ctWyNir9jZFAgmB1XdqDfccAbvJFCp1BsdnA8PQuQUEAA) (where it stopped working).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm feeling as a cheater because I used **@aleksxor** `no-type-safe-way` link. Sorry for that, I just thought that it worth some explanation.

I believe [this argument](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34591#issuecomment-544180947) is pretty good:

> This is not an error.
>
> ```typescript
> T = { hello : "bye" }
> ```
>
> Now, your assignment,
>
> ```typescript
> map["hello"] = "hi there"
> ```
>
> Is unsound

Consider the following example:

```js
let index: { [key: string]: any } = {}

let immutable = {
    a: 'a'
} as const

let record: Record<'a', 1> = { a: 1 }

index = immutable // ok
index = record // ok

const foo = (obj: { [key: string]: any }) => {
    obj['sdf'] = 2

    return obj
}

const result1 = foo(immutable) //  safe, see return type 
const result2 = foo(record) // safe , see return type
```

It works, because TS does not try to infer `obj` from generic argument. We can use any string we want as index.

Let's go back to our problem, now, TS tries to infer type of object

```js
const foo = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(obj: T) => {
    obj['sdf'] = 2 // error
}
```

`{[key:string]:any}` is too wide.

Examples of unsoundness:

```js
let index: { [key: string]: any } = {}

let immutable = {
    a: 'a'
} as const

let record: Record<'a', 1> = { a: 1 }

index = immutable // ok
index = record // ok

const foo = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(obj: T) => {
    obj['sdf'] = 2

    return obj
}

const result1 = foo(immutable) //  unsound, see return type 
const result2 = foo(record) // unsound , see return type
```

Hence, while you can get value by key, it is safe to disallow mutations by key.

Btw, TS does not play well with mutations, because it can't track them.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67660342/why-does-typescript-say-this-variable-is-referenced-directly-or-indirectly-in-i) you have another one good example why it is better to avoid mutations

> If TypeScript didn't know the key exists in T, result[key] should be an error regardless of reading or writing. I get why writing may be unsound when reading isn't, I think that first sentence is just a tangent.

If you read property - it can not affect `T` object and you can return `T`  without any problems.

```js
const foo = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(obj: T) => {
    const readOperation = obj['sdf']
    // object still has T type
    return obj
}
```

But if you mutate it:

```js
const foo = <T extends { [key: string]: any }>(obj: T) => {
    obj['sdf'] = 2
    // this is not our good old `T` anymore,
    return obj
}
```

TS can't figure out the return type of function.
Type signature is

```js
const foo: <T extends {
    [key: string]: any;
}>(obj: T) => T
```

But it is not `T` anymore, since it mutated and because TS does not track mutations - it is unsafe to do.

Comment: *"I believe this argument is pretty good."* Please quote the relevant part. Remember some sites are blocked for some people.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with this code.

- There is [no type-safe way](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/34591) to iterate over an object with a generic set of keys.
- `Object.keys` returns `string[]` and that's [itended behavior](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). Though not suitable for iterating over your type.

You may rewrite your function as:

```typescript
function reduceObjects<K extends string, T extends unknown>(currentValue: Record<K, T>, previousValue: Record<K, T>): Record<K, T> {
    const result = Object.assign({}, previousValue) as Record<K, any>;

    for (const key in result) {
        const prev = result[key];
        const curr = currentValue[key];
        if (typeof prev === "number" && typeof curr === "number") {
            result[key] = prev + curr;
        } else if (typeof prev === "string" && typeof curr === "string") {
            result[key] = prev + curr;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

[TS playground](https://tsplay.dev/wOa4Rm)

Comment: Thanks. This might be an answer to [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67809891/is-it-possible-to-reduce-generic-objects-with-unknown-property-names-in-typescri), but it doesn't answer **my** question: **Why** can I use `key` to index `result` in `const prev = result[key];` but not in `result[key] = x`? As I emphasized, that's my question, not how to fix the code. (Actually it may not be an answer to the other question either, as it doesn't ensure that the input objects are the same type, nor provide that type for the result.)

Comment: Updated the answer to impose stronger restrictions on source object types and infer return type. Though it still doesn't answer your main question.

Comment: I used your link in my answer, It was very helpful. I already thanked you! :)