# keyof and React Redux action

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am using React Redux toolkit and keyof to specify that one element of my action payload shall be the key of the type, that my state consists of, so I can update the properties of the state using a redux action.
Anyways it says that:
Type string | number is not assignable to type never.
In this line:

```
state[id][key] = value;
```

Can you give me an explanation what the problem is here?
Thank you very much!

```
interface MyType {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: number;
};

const makeMyType = () => {
  return {
    a: 1,
    b: 'b',
    c: 2
  } as MyType;
}

interface UpdateType<Type> {
  id: number;
  key: keyof Type;
  value: Type[keyof Type];
}

const test_slice = createSlice({
  name: 'test_slice',
  initialState: [makeMyType(), makeMyType()];
  reducers: {
    updateProperty(state: MyType[], action: PayloadAction<UpdateType<MyType>) {
      const {id, key, value} = action.payload;
      state[id][key] = value;
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the classic issue with mutations in typescript.
You can find full and detailed explanation of this [in my blog](https://catchts.com/mutations) and in other SO answers:[ [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834191/why-can-i-index-by-string-to-get-a-property-value-but-not-to-set-it/67836124#67836124), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097) ]

**TL; DR**

> Likewise, multiple candidates for the same type variable in contra-variant positions causes an intersection type to be inferred.

AND

> objects are contravariant in their key types

Hence,  `state[id][key]` produces this error:

```
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'
```

This is because  `string & number = never`. See the first quote:`.... contra-variant positions causes an intersection`.

TypeScript is unsure about `state[id][key] = value`.

This type:

```js
interface UpdateType<Type> {
  id: number;
  key: keyof Type;
  value: Type[keyof Type];
}
```

is weak an allows illegal state to be represented.
Consider next example:

```js
const x: UpdateType<MyType> = {
  id: 2,
  key: 'a',
  value: 's' //<--- should be number
}
```

If you want to make it safer, you should use union of all allowed/legal states:

```js
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

/**
 * Is a union of all valid states
 */
type UpdateType<Type> = Values<{
  [Key in keyof Type]: {
    id: number;
    key: Key;
    value: Type[Key];
  }
}>
```

But it did not help us to resolve the problem.

If you want to fix it , you should go one level up and mutate only `state[id]`. This value has `MyType` type.

There is one iimportant thing we should be aware of - TS does not track mutations.
How we can benefit from this?

Consider this example:

```js
const mutableUpdate = <
  State extends MyType,
  Key extends keyof State,
  Value extends State[Key]
>(state: State, key: Key, value: Value) => {
  state[key] = value;
  return state
}
```

Above function will help us to mutate the state.
Full example:

```js
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

interface MyType {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: number;
};

const makeMyType = (): MyType => ({
  a: 1,
  b: 'b',
  c: 2
})

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

/**
 * Is a union of all valid states
 */
type UpdateType<Type> = Values<{
  [Key in keyof Type]: {
    id: number;
    key: Key;
    value: Type[Key];
  }
}>

const mutableUpdate = <
  State extends MyType,
  Key extends keyof State,
  Value extends State[Key]
>(state: State, key: Key, value: Value) => {
  state[key] = value;
  return state
}

const test_slice = createSlice({
  name: 'test_slice',
  initialState: [makeMyType(), makeMyType()],
  reducers: {
    updateProperty(state: MyType[], action: PayloadAction<UpdateType<MyType>>) {
      const { id, key, value } = action.payload;
      const result = mutableUpdate(state[id], key, value);
      state[id] = result;
    }
  }
});
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQZQDbDJoA0cAChgJ54QYAmAgsjMBAHZwC%20cAZlBCDgByAALo6AVwAeAKwDOAehgQIeANbAYQgLAAoPcDbYoPDETgBZSgBVKYNIj1w4GAFxw2EkACM0UANxOcN7ucjBQhgDmgbrOyO6ePn4xnDF6yOxhcCAYamhWtvZwALxwABQAlO4Fdg7FAHzlCEFucACMxEEhwt5CnbEo7gBMepwVenowtXAAahh4EmhyADzWjaXWANp5lBA8cNYAuhO6CgBUZ05ncACSci5wEmysHHsueHhwAG7zwHRwYSwSyuCkm0wAqmA6EDCmhVrV1rN5osVs0BpsANJoShwQxwHZvWGHdxo5zOP4JLy%20AJBZw7dxYygxMnfZFodywzHYw7MrijeonDJsLIgCQwDDePBoSHQ7AlODLII4cVytBSbBsOj3Gr2frORlwNUarX47FvZVAvVIhYOI1oTX3C3YLmUY66eplQHYdxOkimygM7GkH429xzG0VEqNUkAlVobbc%20Uhxa89AwCRQDhetCjQWZeDYMIAfTkBHMpVQmGw%20EIaDKMbYGBA7OEhZgJbLaD6QUMmmA8197k2OTyOrrFVII-yNlqlUOVvEEiIUDkJNpjyhQLI-HssEonrj1Rn9k285czBe7go1FojAv7GWMphtWWY-q9UjMZZQqySD%20pB2YM2S4eUzBYdgADowCoGh6F5b98zgdA5AkPB4FKUVxUlaVN2wA8gU2P4z0A1kI3gsls0IuhDnlZDUJgcjOCCJjdDGfwgA)