# Why ts will infer to `never` when I lack index signature?

Tags: typescript

When I didn't add index signature in `FormData`:

```js
interface FormData {
  applicationName: string;
  cluster: string;
  stackCode: number;
  GitHubToken: string;
}

enum FieldChangeType {
  TextInput,
  Toggle,
}

interface FieldAction {
  type: FieldChangeType;
  field: keyof FormData;
  payload?: FormData[keyof FormData];
}

function useFormRedux() {
  function reducer(preState: FormData, action: FieldAction) {
    const nextState: FormData = cloneDeep(preState);

    switch(action.type) {
      case FieldChangeType.TextInput:
        nextState[action.field] = action.payload!;
        // Error: Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    }

    return nextState;
  }
}
```

When I add index signature in `FormData`, the error is gone:

```js
interface FormData {
  [index: string]: boolean | number | string | string[]
  applicationName: string;
  cluster: string;
  stackCode: number;
  GitHubToken: string;
}
```

This is confuse me **why ts will infer to `never` when I lack an index signature?**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `FormData` is a built in type which looks like this:

```js
interface FormData {
    append(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    delete(name: string): void;
    get(name: string): FormDataEntryValue | null;
    getAll(name: string): FormDataEntryValue[];
    has(name: string): boolean;
    set(name: string, value: string | Blob, fileName?: string): void;
    forEach(callbackfn: (value: FormDataEntryValue, key: string, parent: FormData) => void, thisArg?: any): void;
}

interface FormData {
    [Symbol.iterator](): IterableIterator<[string, FormDataEntryValue]>;
    /** Returns an array of key, value pairs for every entry in the list. */
    entries(): IterableIterator<[string, FormDataEntryValue]>;
    /** Returns a list of keys in the list. */
    keys(): IterableIterator<string>;
    /** Returns a list of values in the list. */
    values(): IterableIterator<FormDataEntryValue>;
}
```

Hence, I think it is a good idea to rename your custom interface.

Error:

```js
Type 'string | number' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.(2322)
```

in

```
nextState[action.field] = action.payload!;
```

From type perspective `action.payload` might be `string | number | undefined` and `action.field` might be any key from `CustomFormData`. It means that there is no straight corelation between `action.field` and `action.payload`.

Further more,

```js
interface FieldAction {
    type: FieldChangeType;
    field: keyof CustomFormData;
    payload?: CustomFormData[keyof CustomFormData];
}
```

is very unsafe.
Consider this:

```js
const unsafeAction: FieldAction = {
    type: FieldChangeType.TextInput,
    field: 'cluster',
    payload: 42
}
```

THis object has invalid representation, because `payload` should be string.

In order to fix it, you should make invalid state unrepresentable. Consider this example:

```js
type FieldAction = {
    [Field in keyof CustomFormData]: {
        type: FieldChangeType,
        field: Field,
        payload?: CustomFormData[Field]
    }
}[keyof CustomFormData]

const ok: FieldAction = {
    type: FieldChangeType.TextInput,
    field: 'cluster',
    payload: 'str'
} // ok

const expected_error: FieldAction = {
    type: FieldChangeType.TextInput,
    field: 'cluster',
    payload: 42
} // error
```

We have created a union of all allowed states. Btw, TypeScript does not like mutations, you should always take it into account.

Here is my suggestion how to do it:

```js
interface CustomFormData {
    applicationName: string;
    cluster: string;
    stackCode: number;
    GitHubToken: string;
}

enum FieldChangeType {
    TextInput,
    Toggle,
}

type FieldAction = {
    [Field in keyof CustomFormData]: {
        type: FieldChangeType,
        field: Field,
        payload?: CustomFormData[Field]
    }
}[keyof CustomFormData]


const makePayload = (state: CustomFormData, action: FieldAction)
    : CustomFormData => ({
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.payload
    })

function useFormRedux() {
    function reducer(preState: CustomFormData, action: FieldAction) {
        const nextState: CustomFormData = null as any;

        switch (action.type) {
            case FieldChangeType.TextInput:
                return makePayload(preState, action)
        }

        return nextState;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mZ48Jw)

[Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) you can find offixial explanation

Here you can find more questions/answers about htis topic:
[first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097), [almost a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68576735/keyof-and-react-redux-action/68578198#68578198)

[Here](https://catchts.com/mutations) you can find my article with some examples and links

**Explanation of main utility**

```js
type FieldAction = {
    /**
     * This syntax mean iteration
     * See docs https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html
     */
    [Field in keyof CustomFormData]: {
        type: FieldChangeType,
        field: Field,
        payload?: CustomFormData[Field]
    }
}

/**
 * I have removed [keyof CustomFormData] from the end for the sake of readability
 * You can instead wrap FieldAction into Values utility type
 */

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]
{
    type Test1 = Values<{ a: 1, b: 2 }> // 1 | 2
}

type Result = Values<FieldAction>
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WJy4km)

Comment:  Can you explain this segment:
```
type FieldAction = {
    [Field in keyof CustomFormData]: {
        type: FieldChangeType,
        field: Field,
        payload?: CustomFormData[Field]
    }
}[keyof CustomFormData]
```
It's hard to understand for me.

Comment: @Pandy made an update