# Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'this'

Tags: typescript

The parent class method updates the properties of the child class, but I get these error messages. How can I solve this problem.

index.ts code:

```js
class A {
  animate<
    K extends keyof this,
    T extends {
      [key in K]: this[key] extends number ? this[key] : never
    }
  >(props: Partial<T>) {

    const initialValue: Partial<T> = {}
    const changeValue: Partial<T> = {}

    for (let key in props) {
      initialValue[key] = this[key]
      changeValue[key] = props[key] - this[key]
    }

    // ...
  }
}

class B extends A {
  width: number
  heigth: number
  name: string
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.heigth = 20
    this.width = 20
    this.name = 'B'
  }
}

const b = new B();

b.animate({
  width: 40,
  heigth: 40
})
```

Error message:

ERROR in /project/app/index.ts(13,27)
TS2536: Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'this'.

ERROR in /project/app/index.ts(14,7)
TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>] | undefined'.

ERROR in /project/app/index.ts(14,26)
TS2362: The left-hand side of an arithmetic operation must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.

ERROR in /project/app/index.ts(14,39)
TS2536: Type 'Extract<keyof T, string>' cannot be used to index type 'this'.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `class A` knows nothing about `this` of `B`.

`this` of `class A` has only one method `animate`.

I believe that you should declare `animate` property in class `B`.
Do you have a control over the `A` class ?
This line `[key in K]: this[key] extends number ? this[key] : never` will not work in a way you expect.

Both `A` and `B` have different `this` context.

Consider this example:

```js
class A {
  animate<
    K extends keyof this,
    T extends {
      [key in K]: number
    }
  >(this: Record<string, T[Extract<keyof T, string>]>, props: T) {

    const initialValue: Partial<T> = {}
    const changeValue: Record<string, number> = {}

    for (let key in props) {
      initialValue[key] = this[key]
      changeValue[key] = props[key] - this[key]
    }

    // ...
    return {initialValue, changeValue}
  }
}

class B extends A {
  width: number
  heigth: number
  name: string

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.heigth = 20
    this.width = 20
    this.name = 'B'
  }
}
const b = new B();

const result = b.animate({ // <-------------------- Error
  width: 40,
  heigth: 40
})
```

> The 'this' context of type 'B' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Record<string, number>'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'B'

While there are no errors inside class implementation, you can't call `b` with context of `A`.

If you don't want to change inheritance model you can use this code as a workaround:

```js
interface Indexed {
  [prop: string]:
  | number
  | string
  | (<K extends keyof this,
    T extends {
      [key in K]: number
    }>(props: T) => void)
}

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

class A {
  [prop: string]:
  | number
  | string
  | (<K extends keyof this,
    T extends {
      [key in K]: number
    }>(props: T) => void)

  animate<
    Keys extends PropertyKey,
    Value extends number,
    Props extends Record<Keys, Value>
  >(props: Props) {

    const initialValue: Indexed = {}
    const changeValue: Indexed = {}

    for (let key in props) {
      initialValue[key] = this[key]
      changeValue[key] = props[key] - (this[key] as number)

      // ...
    }
  }
}

class B extends A {
  width: number
  heigth: number
  name: string

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.heigth = 20
    this.width = 20
    this.name = 'B'
  }
}
const b = new B();

const result = b.animate({
  width: 40,
  heigth: 40
})
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIgCYQB4Q8gbwFgAoZZAbQAcoB7KgLmQGcwpQBzAXQdPIB9kIAK4BbAEbQ%20yQa3YgO0wQAoAPAGlkOSJmbIA1hACetGMjAALYMwA008gBUt2HRj3Ey5LxUNHkoZHUeITFJKHtkAF8APmUaemYmBwBKZABeaOQAN1pgDGTSSNJSMCMqFAA1OAAbYQhmVQdMtOQHH2NTVq5ikgRquGY9AEFCaWo6RhY2Th4lEIkpT1lphTm1TW0IXQMOs0trO09HZ1d3CPJ2vwCgphEF8KOo2PiqRNbUjOzc-J7yOBBgKI4JBVBF1MY9JttgAFCbQUrgoyHLzIKq1FBQtzzMLIrywhInLZYgBKEAQtCgGA0EJsqJqdWi0meEze%20NeqQ8EXJIFY-gBYGANTRdSY6CwuHwLQIRUe3N5CAs-w4EGFEFFmBweHShBlERgFOQymqEDAOyuIGQL2YHPOfOAAqF9Igly42v2zBdtoVSpVTpd2qt-oAtIb3f6BtjoAUSLaAPSx5AAOmTERl5Blut6-UGyAAQoTtiMPOQAO55Sy3UKLcgWCDADgVyMPcggOCiNVTeSKGOeOVsYQIMAU5Q2x7MYTlKAjgDcEXdidr9cs2oATAAGOdWZiJssYZctdeb6yJ1vt7UAclz5%20kGdIfeQ4m1IAgJbzM5696g9WE1VNLXEib-ICwIQMoxbILujYACxrrii4NhYTAwYUyRAA)

P.S. Try to avoid mutations in TypeScript.

See [my article](https://catchts.com/mutations) and related answers: [ [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67857960/how-to-selectively-assign-from-one-partial-to-another-in-typescript/67860407#67860407), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67834191/why-can-i-index-by-string-to-get-a-property-value-but-not-to-set-it/67836124#67836124), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68189542/typescript-why-cant-i-assign-a-valid-field-of-an-object-with-type-a-a-b/68190097#68190097), [TS improvement](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769) ]